# Documentation Tool with Little or Incomplete Code

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, documentation, generator

I am looking for a documentation tool. The needs that I have are pretty specific I guess but seems like something that would exist. I have search High and Low and my last resort is the minds of stackoverflow users.

Here is the problem that I am facing. In a language like JavaScript it doesn't really have a classical object oriental nature.

But there are ways to do that with the prototype property.
(if you are confused a little bit look coffeescript output or typescript).

So now once we get here we need to document the code but we don't have certain keywords that we would like to use now.
Such as class and extend.

If you are a bit confused here is an example

```
function Person(name){
   this.name=name;
}

function Person(name){
   return {
       name:name
   }
}

function Person(){
   console.log("hi i am a person");
}
```

All of this is valid javascript and it's damn near impossible without being a human being to tell the intention of the function or the class.

for example

```
function Person(){
   console.log("hi i am a person");
}

///This is obviously not a class only an idiot would think so

Person.prototype.setUp=function(config){
    this.name=config.name;
    this.age=config.age;
}
///Ha-ha! got you it is going to be a class
```

This make it very difficult to document.

So what I want is a way to create documentation that doesn't depend on the code. If I can create it in a separate folder.

If I have a tree like this.

```
src/

    People

           Person.js

           Man.js

           Woman.js

doc/

   index.html

   People
           Person.html

           Man.html

           Woman.html
```

The Problem with doing this by hand is creating each of the files. Giving them a head tag and and style and making the relative links if stuff gets's moved around it creates problems.

I want something that is like the generated documentation from phpdoc with all the style and everything included and i can just browse the classes on the side. With the folder structure and everything included.

KK so so what have i tried.
I tried using markdown. Reason to stop. It was hard to create links that can be clicked and easily navigated. Remember this is suppose to be a GUI front end. That a developer can skim through the pages and understand certain features of the language.

Yes when u upload the github the markdown is parse and understood but it's not good enough needs to work on front end and local.

Wiki
Yes but no. This require a setup. This needs to be a setup less function.

EverNote how are you suppose to sync through github using Evernote. You are able to link and click to jump to different pages, but no options to uses VC.

Microsoft Word. Yes. we can type but to have it formated takes quite a bit of time.

HTML Documents. This is by far the closes thing that works but requires too much time to add those head tags with the relative link to the style tag.

Options place all html in the same folder and use _ as  / This is messy.

How can I get documentation like phpdoc without having any code to generate from. I would like to type it up and then have it generated.

No subscription service.

I have heard some words that seems like a solution might be found in latex but haven't quite figured it out.

Comment: did you look into jsdoc and others like it? you can also use html inside your js file in comments, to rake it out later, or use in-place by serving the file as text/html

Comment: Like i want a clean way to do extend. I don't think that jsdoc has and @extend. 
Because of EcmaScript 6 we are going to have things like extend but i can't find a way to document that presently

Comment: I have double checked jsdoc doesn't support extend

Comment: js doesn't support extend either (instantiation-time sub-class parameter relaying), so i don't see that as counting against documenting clean code. Perhaps you can use external, instance, mixes, and/or mixin, to more precisely document the logistics of your code, or create your own with a slight modification (not recommended for portability reasons).

Comment: No it doesn't but you can simulate it none the less please look at 
jon's page [http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/] or typescript [http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/extending-classes-and-interfaces-using-typescript] or the upcoming ecmascript 6 standards http://www.sencha.com/blog/toward-modern-web-apps-with-ecmascript-6/
In general any modular code created now should take into account the direction the web is going. I hope this will the need to say things like what javascript currently support as we look towards what it will support.

Comment: in stuff like that, extend is just a user-land function, which doesn't really justify a tag anymore than "@isPrime" or "@Math.random()", but you can still use whatever doc keywords you want to describe it. you likely won't find something pre-built to fit a personal and unique need is all i'm saying...

Comment: yes but where as '@isPrime' is not an well known convention i would believe '@extend' is. I hope there is a difference seen in that no? for example never extend prototype is a rule, unless it is a well known convention. like Array.prototype.foreach for older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't mark this as the final answer yet but it definitely looks promising http://daux.io/